# error al ingresar un enter en un input type text

Tags: php, javascript, html5, bootstrap, phpmyadmin

tengo un problema muy serio y no se como solucionarlo tengo este formulario,

```
<form>  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

En mi textArea, al momento de guardar texto a mi base de datos lo realiza sin problema.
Al momento de que ingreso un texto grande y dentro del textArea le doy enter para seguir escribiendo lo guarda pero me da un error y el formulario ya no se puede ver.
Como puedo solucionar?.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la imagen donde dice

```
detallePago:"Retoque"
```

cuando se le da enteren el textArea el resultado es la comilla que cierra se muestra en una linea hacia abajo como el ejemplo

```
detallePago:"Retoque
"
```

El error que me muestra es error de toquen ""

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? Especifícialo claramente en la pregunta

Comment: ya edite la pregunta espero se entienda, estoy utilizando fullCalendar

Comment: Cuando guardes el contenido del textArea has un [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/Trim) al texto para eliminar ese salto de línea. Si quieres conservar el/los salto/s de línea entonces sería bueno ver cómo obtienes los `events`.